# PowerMockRule together with EasyMock NOT Moquito

Tags: java, junit, easymock, powermock

I'm on a legacy project , using EasyMock with no option to include Mockito, that being said I've been having trouble getting a unit test to work with the PowerMockRule.  Nearly all examples I find on how to  utilize the rule is being made with Mockito.  I could really use some help figuring this out with EasyMock.

```
@RunWith(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.class)
public class ModuleCloningServiceImplTest {

  @Rule
  public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
  //...

  @Test
  public void copyModuleToPages_success_customLayoutTileCopy_default_tile() {           
    ModuleType moduleType = getModuleType(ModuleTypeCode.COUPON, 2, 3);
    Module<CouponViewer> module = getModule(1L, moduleType);

    Page copyPage = getPage(1L, moduleType);
    PageLayout newPageLayout = DomainObjectBuilder.newPageLayout().build();
    newPageLayout.setCode(PageLayoutCode.CUSTOM);
    copyPage.setPageLayout(newPageLayout);
    List<Page> pages = Arrays.asList(copyPage);

    PowerMock.mockStatic(CustomPageLayoutUtils.class);
    CustomPageLayoutUtils.tileNumberExistsInCustomPageLayout(9, null);
    expectLastCall().andReturn(false);
    CustomPageLayoutUtils.getPreferredOrDefaultTile(copyPage, moduleType);
    expectLastCall().once().andReturn(2);

    PowerMock.replayAll();
    OperationReport operationReport = moduleCloningService.copyModuleToPages(module, pages, 9);
    PowerMock.verifyAll();

    checkCopySuccessInPages(pages);
    for (Page page : pages) {
      for (ModulePage<? extends JaxbModule> modulePage : page.getModulePages()) {
        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2), modulePage.getTileNumber());
      }
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(operationReport.isSuccesful());
  }
```

Each call to CustompPageLayoutUtils is entering the method instead of using the mock.  I've tried a few permuations on this code but this was my last try.  Any insight would be very welcome.  I hope there are other people that could make use to a solution for this issue.

Comment: Don't know much about PowerMock, but is this anything to do with a lack of `@PrepareForTest`?

Comment: Also [this page](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) seems to claim that you don't need the `@RunWith` when you use the `@Rule` annotation.....

Comment: Indeed I don't need it if I where to write a test from scratch.  However this is a legacy test that needs to be expanded.  If I remove the runswith ... well everything fails so I need to keep it.  Hence my need for Rule.  If I would run with PowerMockRunner I can get my test to work, but then the other tests fail.  The most pragmatic way would be to just write another test class and run that with PowerMockRunner.  But that's just so ugly, I like to do it right and not with a workaround.  I'll investigate the PrepareForTest but I sincerely doubt that would be it, could be though.

Comment: I've seen the order of methods usage on the PowerMock and noticed that you are not following it. On the wiki page of PowerMock the very first example show that it mock the static class, do the expect on the method, then do a replay and call the method of the test. The example I saw is here [powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) so, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it this afternoon I'll let you know the results

Comment: I switched some statements around as in the example but it was a no go, it still went into the actual method instead of mocking it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to give in and just created another test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { CustomPageLayoutUtils.class })
public class ModuleCloningServiceImplPowermockTest {

  private ModuleCloningServiceImpl moduleCloningService;

  private final CouponViewer moduleContent = new CouponViewer();

  private final PageLayout pageLayout = DomainObjectBuilder.newPageLayout().build();

  private Site site;

  private Product product;

  private CrudDao crudDao;

  private AuditLogger auditlogger;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    moduleCloningService = new ModuleCloningServiceImpl();
    crudDao = PowerMock.createMock(CrudDao.class);
    auditlogger = PowerMock.createMock(AuditLogger.class);
    ReflectionUtils.setByType(moduleCloningService, crudDao);
    ReflectionUtils.setByType(moduleCloningService, auditlogger);
    product = new Product(1L);
    site = DomainObjectBuilder.newSite().withId(1l).withProduct(product).build();

    PowerMock.mockStatic(CustomPageLayoutUtils.class);
  }  

  @Test
  public void copyModuleToPages_success_customLayoutTileCopy_default_tile() {


    ModuleType moduleType = getModuleType(ModuleTypeCode.COUPON, 2, 3);
    Module<CouponViewer> module = getModule(1L, moduleType);

    Page copyPage = getPage(1L, moduleType);
    PageLayout newPageLayout = DomainObjectBuilder.newPageLayout().build();
    newPageLayout.setCode(PageLayoutCode.CUSTOM);
    copyPage.setPageLayout(newPageLayout);
    List<Page> pages = Arrays.asList(copyPage);

    CustomPageLayoutUtils customPageLayoutUtils = PowerMock.createMock(CustomPageLayoutUtils.class);

    customPageLayoutUtils.tileNumberExistsInCustomPageLayout(9, null);
    expectLastCall().andReturn(false);
    customPageLayoutUtils.getPreferredOrDefaultTile(copyPage, moduleType);
    expectLastCall().andReturn(1);
    crudDao.save(EasyMock.anyObject());
    expectLastCall();
    auditlogger.audit(EasyMock.anyObject(AuditLogEntry.class));

    PowerMock.replayAll();
    OperationReport operationReport = moduleCloningService.copyModuleToPages(module, pages, 9);
    PowerMock.verifyAll();

    checkCopySuccessInPages(pages);
    for (Page page : pages) {
      for (ModulePage<? extends JaxbModule> modulePage : page.getModulePages()) {
        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(1), modulePage.getTileNumber());
      }
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(operationReport.isSuccesful());
  }
}
```

It works but it isn't perfect, thanks to those trying to help me out though !